# The difference between /mnt/user, /mnt/installer and /mnt/androidwritable in Android external storage

Tags: android

Are /mnt/user, /mnt/installer and /mnt/androidwritable used for permission control? If so, how are permissions controlled through these different mount points?

I haven't found any code that selects different permissions by judging these paths.
Does anyone know who can explain it?